# Async inside filter function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filter

`const result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(async (n) => n <= 3)`

If you console.log(result) you get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Why isn't it [1, 2, 3]?

If you remove async from the function you do get [1, 2, 3].

I just want to know why it works like that.

Comment: What is the use case of using `async` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: It looks like the built-in filter function uses `Function.call()` under the hood to execute your filter function. That seems likely to break the `async`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the async function contents. It's because async functions return a promise which is truthy. Therefore it will return all elements

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`filter` creates a new array with all the values from the original array where the function you pass returns a *true* value.

`async` functions return Promises. Promises are objects. Objects are *true* values.

---

If you wanted to do this with async functions, you would need to wait until you have resolved the promises before testing for truthiness.

```js
!async function() {

  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const promises = data.map(async(n) => ({
    value: n,
    include: n <= 3
  }));
  const data_with_includes = await Promise.all(promises);
  const filtered_data_with_includes = data_with_includes.filter(v => v.include);
  const filtered_data = filtered_data_with_includes.map(data => data.value);
  console.log(filtered_data);

}();
```

Or, in a format that doesn't explain each step:

```js
!async function() {

  const result = (await Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(async(n) => ({
    value: n,
    include: n <= 3
  })))).filter(v => v.include).map(data => data.value);

  console.log(result);

}();
```

---

You could also avoid using the functional methods in favour of mutation in a `for` loop

```js
!async function() {

  const test = async(n) => n <= 3;
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const value = data[i];
    if (await test(value)) result.push(value);
  }

  console.log(result);

}();
```

Comment: `const result = await Promise.all(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(async (n) => n <= 3)
);`

This is how the code looked in my coding interview. (Assume this is part of a bigger async function). I just got rid of Promise stuff to simplify the question and figure out why async affects it like that

Comment: @karoge — Well that's nonsense. `Promise.all` needs to be passed an array of promises, not an array of numbers.

Comment: That's what I told them lol. I had to guess what would be inside "result" after executing the code. I said it would give an error because of Promise.all stuff but apparently I was wrong and it actually returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Yes. It's pointless nonsense, not error throwing nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

I stuck with the same issue so you can implement async filter fn:

```
async function asyncFilter<T>(arr: T[], cb: (el: T) => Promise<boolean>): Promise<T[]> {
    const filtered: T[] = [];

    for (const element of arr) {
        const needAdd = await cb(element);

        if (needAdd) {
            filtered.push(element);
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}
```